# Blog posts look like Meta Stack Exchange posts; mistakenly display "Meta Stack Exchange" in the icon tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, community-bulletin, icons

On Music, I saw this little bar on the right:

[image: A blog post with the MSE icon next to it and then two Hot Meta Posts]

This is weird. I don't read things closely and thus didn't see "Blog", so I clicked on it thinking "hmm, is this some very unusual announcement?" based on it having the blue-and-white Meta logo.

I found this:

[image: Screenshot of a bit of the blog post]

*That's no Meta!!* This is a leftover icon from the thing where non-Meta sites would show Meta posts on the right; [its alt text is "Meta Stack Exchange"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO6hv.png). **Can this be changed to the Stack Overflow logo or something to make it clear that these are SO blog posts?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This has been changed, and now shows a pencil icon instead:

[image: blog icon is pencil]

Comment: You stole my thunder @shadow. Blog icon has indeed been updated.

Comment: @Yaakov thunder should be quick, so not my fault. ;)

Comment: I've clicked on this pencil dozens of times, but I still can't get it to display the revision history...

Comment: @Cody I expected it to let me edit the title. ;)