# Pencil or edit icon for blog posts in sidebar?

Tags: support, bug, blog, sidebar

There is a icon for the blog posts in the sidebar. Previously it was displayed with Meta Stack Exchange icon, but now it with pencil or edit icon.

Is this expected or a bug?

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: posts]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blog posts look like Meta Stack Exchange posts; mistakenly display "Meta Stack Exchange" in the icon tooltip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341978/blog-posts-look-like-meta-stack-exchange-posts-mistakenly-display-meta-stack-e)